# Как сделать второе условие в компараторе?

Tags: java

Как добавить второе и третье дополнительное условие сортировки?

```
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Stock>() {
            public int compare(Stock stock1, Stock stock2) {
                return ((String)stock1.get("name")).compareTo((String)stock2.get("name"));
            }
        });
```

Comment: java 8 доступна?

Comment: Да, доступна java 8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public int compare(Stock stock1, Stock stock2) {
    int res = ((String)stock1.get("a")).compareTo((String)stock2.get("a"));
    return res != 0 ? ((String)stock1.get("b")).compareTo((String)stock2.get("b")) : res;
}
```

Для нескольких условий:

```
public int compare(Smth x, Smth y) {
    int res;

    if ((res = x.a.compareTo(y.a)) != 0) return res;
    if ((res = x.b.compareTo(y.b)) != 0) return res;
    if ((res = x.c.compareTo(y.c)) != 0) return res;
    if ((res = x.d.compareTo(y.d)) != 0) return res;
    if ((res = x.e.compareTo(y.e)) != 0) return res;
    if ((res = x.f.compareTo(y.f)) != 0) return res;
    if ((res = x.g.compareTo(y.g)) != 0) return res;

    return x.h.compareTo(y.h);
}
```

PS: К сожалению, [как на js](//ru.stackoverflow.com/a/432370/178988) не получится.

Comment: @zRrr, дополнил ответ.

Answer (score 3):

Судя по [en-SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25501226/3212712), для 8 Java можно так:

```
Comparator.comparing((Person p)->p.firstName)
      .thenComparing(p->p.lastName)
      .thenComparingInt(p->p.age);
```

**Внимание** этот метод [может кидать NPE](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) если один из объектов - `null`

---

До 8 версии, судя по гуглу, достаточно просто последжовательно сортировать различными простыми компараторами

---

Также можно подключить либу Apache Commons и делать так:

```
public int compare(Person a, Person b){

   return new CompareToBuilder()
     .append(a.getName(), b.getName())
     .append(a.getAddress(), b.getAddress())
     .toComparison();
}
```

Comment: Замечу, что компаратор из первого примера не выполняет проверку на `null` и будет бросать NPE.

Comment: @Nofate, т.е. у них внутри нет на это проверки?.. 0_о как же так(

Comment: @Nofate, хм, да, в доке так и написано. Странная реализация. Добавил в ответ